# <value error> in Bfile

Tags: oracle

my goal is to read an image from database sever location '/data/ '.

with CMD and FTP command I I have ' PUT ' image.png  in the server lcoation /data/.

in pl sql , the directory is /data/. then I created a table with bfile, and insert a value in it.

```
 CREATE TABLE Lob_table (
 Key_value NUMBER NOT NULL,
 F_lob BFILE);

 INSERT INTO Lob_table VALUES
 (23,  BFILENAME('TEST_DIR2', 'image.png'));
```

If I  select the table Lob_table I get < value error >.

If i run this command I also get error :

```
begin
 select F_lob
  into l_bfile
  from Lob_table where Key_value=23 ;
 dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile, dbms_lob.file_readonly );
end;



ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

What am doing wrong ?

Comment: What does `select * from all_directories` return?

Comment: the result will be SYS TEST_DIR2 /data @a_horse_with_no_name .. however I have grant read and write to my user schema

Comment: The error "*No such file or directory*" seems to indicate otherwise

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how to solve my issue ?

Comment: Looks more like the file isn't actually in /data on the server; the directory object seems to exist and be readable, but it can't see the file name you specified. Are you sure you FTP'd it to the right place - you've confirmed `/data/image.png` exists, with the same case for the file name?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes If I write in cmd : pwd .. i get /data/ if write ls I get image.png .. where then is my problem ?

Comment: @Moudiz - might be useful to show exactly what `ls -l /data/image.png` returns, in the question; and verify your permissions on the directory object I suppose, and double-check you're on the right server... otherwise what you have works so not sure what it missing.

Comment: @AlexPoole after I checked the problem, it was in the image.png , when I have selected another , it opened. ill check the problem of the file. thanx